# initializer element is not constant (sqrt function)

Tags: gcc

i would like to define a value with a float type; to be more exact, with the squareroot function.
It should look something like this `#define hyp sqrt(pow(50,2) + pow(50,2))`. 
But for this value it
seems to be not constant, so i have some warnings and type- conflictions.
 For what reason it is not constant?
Is a float number always generated at run-time, and all integers when compiling?
Or is this conflicting because, the sqrt declaration has to be inside some scope of a function?

[edit]
To be more clear:
The warnings are beacause of  some operation with the defined sqrt-value `#define    P + hyp` - and for that i get the warnings. And P is then put into an array, `double arr_ps[] = {P,...}`. There is no problem with integers, just with that sqrt- value.[/edit]

@Simon
I have a header file points.h:

```
#define x             10
#define y             10 
#define distance  100
#define P1x          x
#define P1y          y
#define hyp         sqrt(pow(50,2) + pow(50,2))
#define P1x_new  P1x + distance
#define P1y_new  P1y + hyp
```

Then i have the c file:

```
#include "points.h"

double  arr_x[2]={P1x,P1x_new};
double  arr_y[2]={P1y,P1y_new};

main(){

     printf("Px: %f, Py: %f \n",arr_x[0],arr_y[0]);
     printf("Px_new: %f, Py_new: %f \n", arr_x[1],arr_y[1]);

}
```

The warning:`initializer element is not constant (near initialization for 'arr_y')` - and i get three of them.

Comment: Why are you even using the preprocesser for this ? It should probably just be a constant or an inline function.

Comment: Can you show how you are using `hyp` elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Can you show a succinct, self-contained code example? I tried to replicate your problem and could not do so. I tried a couple of different ways and got no warnings of the sort that you describe from `gcc`.

Comment: @PaulR : I know, that it's not proper use, but just for testing reasons; the point is: how the compiler treats the defined values, when they are integers, and how, when they aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clause 6.6, paragraph 3 of the standard says

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.

that a constant expression must not contain a function-call that is evaluated.

That is because

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

(paragraph 2 ibid), and a function-call may not be possible to evaluate during translation.

In a **constant expression** - and such are needed to initialise objects of static storage duration - you can only use basic arithmetic, `+-*/`, and `sizeof` (but only if the result is an integer constant expression) and `_Alignof`:

> An arithmetic constant expression shall have arithmetic type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, and `_Alignof` expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

The term "constant expression" has a technical meaning that is much narrower than the everyday sense.

Comment: Then what's an floating constant in gcc? Something like Pi? And more over, how to define floating constants?

Comment: You define a floating point constant by assigning it a number rather than the result of a function call: `const float x = 1.0f;` In your case, you should pre-calculate your equation and insert the value.